# Stop php script execution when a browser has been closed

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, php

I have my PHP app running on Nginx & PHP-FPM.

When I used Apache, request abortion (browser closing) terminated php process, but now script continues execution till its end. Nginx `fastcgi_ignore_client_abort` option is `Off` and I do not use `fastcgi_finish_request` function.

What can be reason of such behaviour? Or how can I tell php that request is aborted?

Answer (score 0):

fastcgi leaves processes open and closes the handle within the process of the particular file. this is one of the main differences between fastcgi and regular cgi. also, php has no knowledge of the browser at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason `fast-cgi` typically provides greater performance than `mod_php`. A threaded approach as opposed to forking means there's no overhead of starting up the apache process for each request (or closing it down).

You can configure the amount of children running to tune the amount of resources consumed with the [process manager documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php#pm).